# No intellisense for std::shared_ptr in template class header file in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to std::shared_ptr and trying to use it in linked list implementation. The code is:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(const T& anItem);
    Node(const Node& anNode);

    T getItem() const;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> getNext() const;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> getPrev() const;
    void setItem(const T& anItem);
    void setNext(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> nextNodePtr);
    void setPrev(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> prevNodePtr);
private:
    T item;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> prev;
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(): next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& anItem) : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr), item(anItem) {}

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node& anNode) : next(anNode.getNext()), prev(anNode.getPrev()), item(anNode.getItem()) {}

template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getItem() const
{
    return item;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> Node<T>::getNext() const
{
    return next;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> Node<T>::getPrev() const
{
    return prev;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setItem(const T& anItem)
{
    item = anItem;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setNext(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> nextNodePtr)
{
    next = nextNodePtr;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setPrev(std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> prevNodePtr)
{
    prev = prevNodePtr;
}
```

This is in a header file. In any of these member functions, dereferencing the shared pointer doesn't show up the members and methods.

For example, suppose that in `setPrev()` I typed the following:

`prev->`

Now if it's a raw pointer (I tested with raw pointer), intellisense will show the members and methods available. But for std::shared_ptr intellisense doesn't work, and the only thing I saw is the methods of std::shared_ptr itself (`operator*` for example). I'm wondering what I did wrong?

Additionally, if I type `(*prev).` VS2017 simply tells me:

> IntelliSense: 'No members available'

BTW it works in main.cpp, just not working in the header file, which is painful as I have to check the header files frequently, so I'm wondering I did something wrong with the smart pointer.

Comment: intellisense != compiler, they both behave differently.

Comment: you probably want to have `weak_ptr` for `prev` Btw.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah but at least it works for raw pointer in the same header file, so I'm confused

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure if my grammar for the `std::shared_ptr` is good. Because if IntelliSense doesn't work at all in this case, then it's going to be real painful to write anything in templates...

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I created a main, includes your file, constructed a new node like this `std::shared_ptr<Node<int>> newNode = std::make_shared<Node<int>>(20);` then I type `newNode->` and I see getItem, getNext, getPrev, setItem, setNext, setPrev.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Thanks yeah it works in main.cpp, also works here. But it doesn't work in the header file.

Comment: Intellisense has difficulty inside template classes.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, is there a way to improve it? Not sure how well vscode performs...but thanks for the help Jarod

Comment: In a header file it gets to be a *lot* less obvious if the parser knows about everything.  It has to be #included in a source file that is part of the project and the parser needs to have a shot at understanding enough.  Pretty easy to do that the wrong way around, you'd normally like finishing it before adding the #include, not the right strategy.  If there are a lot of unresolved syntax errors then it does give up eventually.  Doing this incrementally with a compile in between to keep honest is the best approach.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks I think its possible to imclude the cpp at the end of header for template classes, will try it out at home

Comment: Erm, don't put any template implementation code in a .cpp file.  It doesn't have external linkage.

Comment: When you have a concrete type, like `std::shared_ptr<Node<int>>`, it is a lot easier for the intellisense to see the members. When you have just the template `std::shared_ptr<Node<T>>`, there *could* be specializations of `Node<T>` with different members for some types `T`. Makes it a lot harder to produce the correct member list.

Comment: @HansPassant Makes sense, I just tried and it didn't work. Guess I have to code in the dark then...